# Concatenating js files in laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, webpack, concatenation, laravel-mix

I have some js files in my assets and I want to concat them to one app.js file.
This is what I have in my webpack.mix.js file:

```
mix.js([
  'resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js',
  'resources/assets/js/popper.js',
  'resources/assets/js/jquery.js',
  ], 'public/js/app.js');
```

Now I want to use this script in my project :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#someId').delay(2000).slideUp(300);
});
```

But its slide up does not work. When I load the 3 scripts in blade file separately, the function works very well but I need to place all scripts in a single file. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Change it from `mix.js` to `mix.scripts`.

`scripts` is the concatenating function you're looking for when dealing with non-module libraries